# Displaying data in columns with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display some data in columns in php with wordpress. I have the next snippet to do that:

```
 $args = array(
     'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
     'orderby'      => $orderby,
     'show_count'   => $show_count,
     'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
     'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
     'title_li'     => $title,
     'parent'       =>19,
     'hide_empty'   => $empty
);
$columnas=0;
$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
echo '<table><tr>';
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
  $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
   if((($columnas%4)!==0)and($columnas!==0)){
     echo '<td><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a></td>';
     $columnas=$columnas+1;     
     echo 'Las columnas son: '.$columnas.'<br/>';
   }else
   {
     echo 'Columnas es: '.$columnas;
     echo '<td><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a></td></tr><tr>';
   }


}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

So what I'm doing wrong?, I don't get what I want which is a table with four columns and many rows. Surely, it's a silly thing but I don't see it.

Comment: I think you just need to add if((($columnas%4) to the else.. Otherwise you close the column if columnas == 0

Comment: `$columnas=$columnas+1;` should just be `$columnas++;` and put outside of the if statement otherwise it will never increase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need to display the categories in 4 column. Is that so then this code will help you to show in 4 column table.

```
 $args = array(
 'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
 'orderby'      => $orderby,
 'show_count'   => $show_count,
 'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
 'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
 'title_li'     => $title,
 'parent'       =>19,
 'hide_empty'   => $empty
 );
 $columnas=0;
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );

 echo '<table><tr>';
 foreach($all_categories as $cat) {
    if(($columnas%4) == 0 && $columnas > 0)
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    else

    $category_id = $cat->term_id;
    echo '<td><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a></td>';
    $columnas++;
}
$cnt = (($columnas + 1)%4);
if($cnt > 0) {
    echo '<td colspan="' . (($columnas-1) - $cnt) . '"></td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

But my suggetion are you going to display it in 4X list gor for ul li. Easy to do the loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is working logic you just need to put your code in and I hope it will help you.

```
   $all_categories = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    $html = '<table><tr>';
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
        if (($i % 4) == 0 && ($i != 0)) {
            $html .="</tr><tr>";
        }
        $html .="<td>$cat</td>";
        $i++;
    }
    $html .= '</tr></table>';
    echo $html;
```